# List in a class is not dumping to file

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

When i dump the list in the file and restart the program and try to retrieve it, it returns an empty list.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
import pickle
class student():
    s1marks=[]
    def getdata(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.s1marks.append(i)
    def outdata(self):
        print self.s1marks

def einput():
    f=open('student1.dat','ab')
    e=student()
    e.getdata()
    pickle.dump(e,f)
    f.close()
def edisplay():
    f=open('student1.dat','rb')
    try:
        while True:
            e=pickle.load(f)
            e.outdata()
    except EOFError:
        pass
    f.close()
```

Running the program.

```
>>> einput()
>>> edisplay()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>>
```

Restarted the program and ran the display function

```
>>> edisplay()
[]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have created `student.s1marks` as a class attribute and not an instance attribute. Pickle only records instance attributes.

Make this change:

```
class student():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1marks=[]
    # ... and the rest unchanged
```

Comment: For those may feel puzzled, read the doc [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Answer (score 1):

s1marks is a class attribute and not an attribute of the instance that you are pickling. When you pickled the instance you haven't pickled the class attributes, just the instance attributes. So when you unpickle it you get just the instance attributes back. Which means that the class attributes are generated/initialised then (in this case the empty list)

You should read about instance vs. class attributes in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

A simple way around this is to initialise the list in the `__init__` function of the class instead on the static scope.

Another way would be to change the attribute to be immutable after you assigned it (such as to convert it to a tuple), but this is a workaround that is less recommended